# promise with ng if in ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, promise

Below is my code with return boolean promise

```js
BluetoothEnabled():any {

    this.print.isBluetoothPrinterEnabled().then(
      
        () => { return true},
        () => { return false}
      )
}
```

This is my ionic button with ngif which is not working

```html
<ion-button expand="block"
    (click)="startScanning()" *ngIf= 'BluetoothEnabled()'>scan</ion-button>
```

It goes to infinite loop ..what need to be changed

EDIT:

[image]

EDIT:

```js
startScanning() {

    this.pairedDevices = null;
        this.unpairedDevices = null;
        this.gettingDevices = true;
        const unPair = [];
        this.print.dicoverBluetoothUnPairedPrinter().then((success) => {
          success.forEach((value, key) => {
            var exists = false;
            ....
            
          });
          this.unpairedDevices = unPair;
          this.gettingDevices = false;
        },
          (err) => {
            console.log(err);
          });
      
        this.print.searchBluetoothPrinter().then((success) => {
          this.pairedDevices = success;
        },
          (err) => {
            console.log(err);
          });
        }
```

This is scanning function for scanning device .it will scan paired and unpaired devices>>>

Comment: "not working" is not a problem description. What happens? Why is that wrong? Quote any errors in full.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiples problems with your code.

First of them `BluetoothEnabled()` doesn't return a boolean promise. You need to add the `return` statement in order to return anything. If you had typed the return type of the function, the compiler would have detected this problem.

```js
 BluetoothEnabled(): Promise<boolean> {
    
   **return** this.print.isBluetoothPrinterEnabled().then(
      
        () => { return true},
        () => { return false}
      );
  }
```

Second, `*ngIf` is checking the value returned by the function, if the value is a promise, it will always be true.

```js
let test = new Promise<boolean>(() => false);

if (test)
    console.log("Not okay");
```

OUTPUT

```
Not okay
```

You need to tell Angular that you result is asynchronous by using the [Async pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe).

```html
 <ion-button expand="block"
  (click)="startScanning()" *ngIf= 'BluetoothEnabled() | async'>scan</ion-button>
```

Be aware that you need to have imported the `CommonModule` in your module in order to use it.

Comment: Thanks @Macro..Whether i have to change BluetoothEnabled() function?

Comment: @Ajt I'm sorry, I don't understand your question. the first example of my code is the correction of `BluetoothEnabled` function.

Comment: @Macro i have changed the code..but still same issue..BluetoothEnabled() looping

Comment: The console message is in the `startScanning` function ? If yes, can you provide that function too ?

Comment: Added in question..But that code works fine before..after adding ngif i getting error message..if i remove nf if works fine

Comment: @Macro What is the issue..Is it possibe to fix??Thanks

Comment: @Ajt Is the log in your screenshot `bluetoothSerial.isEnabled: true` from your code ?

Comment: It's hard to tell because I can't debug your code. Might be a ChangeDetection issue. Try setting a class variable "isEnable" and assigning the value, so you use that variable in you `*ngIf` instead of calling a function.